# No driver for AMD 530 graphics on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amdgpu

How can I install AMD 530 graphics for Ubuntu 20.04?
I tried using these [steps](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-10) but there is no support for this specific driver. Is there any solution to this?

The ubuntu installs a gpu driver for my AMD graphics card but it doesn't match with my version of the card. Such that my card is AMD radeon 530 and it installs for AMD Radeon™ RX 550/560/570/580/590 Series Graphics.

Comment: You don't need any driver. And it doesn't matter which GPU is that. Kernel supports all of them. This is not like in Windows where you need drivers to be installed for near to each piece of hardware.

Comment: but when I perform Lenovo hardware diagnosis it doesn't detect the GPU it throws some error like something related to OpenCL. And what's the proof it detects the exact GPU and it works.

Comment: I have no idea what is "Lenovo hardware diagnosis". Is it a Linux program? You can check by `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` and `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` commands.

Comment: 01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445 / 530/535 / 620/625 Mobile] (rev c3)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445 / 530/535 / 620/625 Mobile]
 Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
 Kernel modules: amdgpu
                                                                                                                                
 .This is a wrong GPU which is detected by Ubuntu. I use Radeon 530 grapics.

Comment: It is not wrong. You can see that it is listed, but even if it didn't, it doesn't really matter. This is not how it works. `amdgpu` is the driver for all of those.

Comment: any task which will show me that the ubuntu uses my GPU

Comment: i wrote it already: `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`