# Installing AMD Radeon 530 driver on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, 20.04, graphics, radeon

I have recently dual booted Ubuntu 20.04 on my windows laptop.
My laptop is Dell Inspiron 15 5570 with

> Graphic Cards : Intel UHD 620 && 4 GB AMD Radeon 530 Discrete GPU

Ubuntu detected the intel one but not the Radeon. Do I have to install the appropriate drivers of AMD and are they available for linux?
I have used the below commands to check my drivers.

```
>~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
```

Below are the setting in Softwares and Updates
[image: OtherSoftware]
[image: AdditionalDrivers]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301580/no-driver-for-amd-530-graphics-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Check with `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` and `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` commands.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251302/dont-find-amd-radeon-530-after-installing-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-20

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/amd-radeon-ubuntu-20-04-driver-installation